# MediaRecorder No Metadata on Download

Tags: web-audio-api, mediarecorder

I'm using MediaRecorder (along with the Web Audio API) to record and process audio and download the blob that it generates. The recording and downloading work great, but there is no metadata when the file is downloaded (length, sample rate, channels, etc.)

I'm using this to create the blob, and I've also tried the mimetype with no luck:

```
  const blob = new Blob(chunks, {
   'type' : 'audio/wav'
  });
  chunks = [];
  const audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  audio.src = audioURL;
  console.log("recorder stopped");

  var new_file = document.getElementById('downloadblob').src
  var download_link = document.getElementById("download_link");
  download_link.href = new_file;
  var name = generateFileName();
  download_link.download = name;
```

How could I ensure the length of the recording, sample rate, and other metadata are included in the download?

Comment: What browser are you using?  I tried something similar with Chrome, and I think it only supports webm.  Firefox says it's saving a wav file, but it seems it's actually an Ogg file.  The webm file has no duration, but has the sample rate and is stereo. Firefox produces a file with a duration, bitrate, sample rate and number of channels.

Comment: I'm in Chrome. Even if I had to calculate length and channels that would be fine. I'm not sure how to pass that info to the blob or download link though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any browser which allows you to record something as `audio/wav`. You can get the mimeType of your recording from the instance of the `MediaRecorder`.

```
const blob = new Blob(chunks, {
    'type': mediaRecorder.mimeType
});
```

Please note that the length will only be correct if you omit the `timeslice` parameter when calling `mediaRecorder.start()`. Otherwise the browser doesn't know the final length of the file when generating the metadata.

Comment: thank you for the reply! I tried changing the type to mediaRecorder.mimeType but now I'm getting .weba files. When I had 'audio/wav' in the type section it downloaded the file and played, but there were no metadata to use in my DAW (pro tools).

Comment: What's crazy is that I can take the file, upload it on another page where I'm using the web audio API to process the data, and then I can download it as an encoded wav file with metadata. It's only when trying to use MediaRecorder that I'm running into this.

Comment: How do you encode the wav file?  Yourself?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to mimic that process, but it is built around reading an uploaded file (from an input tag).

Comment: If you don't specify a mimeType when creating your MediaRecorder it will produce a webm file in Chrome right now for audio streams. You can't change that afterwards. I can only assume what that other site which processes the data with the Web Audio API does but I guess it will re-encode the data.

Comment: I think you're exactly right. From what I've read on using a FileReader to process and encode an audio file, I think you have to have a user upload the file as an input. So, this may be an impossible gap for the user, where the user must download the file and then find a way to encode it. It would be nice if this could all be done at once.